# Javascript: save way to read GET without PHP

Tags: javascript, get

I know about GET variables and javascript there are many questions, but I do not understand or get them to work.

I have a html formular, and I need to populate a field with the value of the get variable. The url has 2 variables, here an example:

```
?pid=form.html&id=9869118
```

This page is a html only, so I cannot use php, but I want to (firstly) alert, the value of id.

I have tried so many different versions of solutions here and from google.

(For example:
http://www.onlineaspect.com/2009/06/10/reading-get-variables-with-javascript/

Please help me to understand how its done correctly and save! Please note, I have no jquery either.

Here is what I have tried so far. This is inside the `<script>` tags inside my form.html

```
var GETDATA = new Array();
var sGet = window.location.search;
if (sGet)
{
    sGet = sGet.substr(1);
    var sNVPairs = sGet.split("&");
    for (var i = 0; i < sNVPairs.length; i++)
    {
        var sNV = sNVPairs[i].split("=");
        var sName = sNV[0];
        var sValue = sNV[1];
        GETDATA[sName] = sValue;
    }
}
if (GETDATA["id"] != undefined) {
    document.forms.otayhteytta.id.value = GETDATA["id"];
    }
```

Comment: A useful article: http://papermashup.com/read-url-get-variables-withjavascript/

Comment: and "when" are you try to get the `GET` variables? do you have an even or something?

Comment: Thanks @aug I tried this one too, did not work either.

Comment: @badZoke all I have is this code, I thought the `window.location.search` does the job?

Comment: I think he's just trying to get the parameters passed to the page in Javascript, even if the OP does not do anything with them server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a pure JavaScript function for that like so:

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
    results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

And then you can alert the value of 'id' like so:

```
alert(getParameterByName('id'));
```

You can check if the parameter exists using a simple 'if' condition:

```
var id = getParameterByName('id');
if (id != "") {
    alert(id);
}
```

Source: [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values)

Comment: and what is `name`, that's getting passed to the function?

Comment: @Kaktus this does NOT require jQuery :)

Comment: oh sorry in the linked question they were talking about jquery, I try this one

Comment: no worries, the linked question's solution actually doesn't rely on jQuery.

Comment: I tried it like you said, but it alerts me only an empty window? Not even undefined? (console shows no js errors)

Comment: Oh sorry @SoftwareGuy my fault! it works! I need only a fallback when the GET id is not set

Comment: it works fine on my end. Can you update your question with the code you tried? I will update my answer to add complete HTML file as sample.

Comment: @SoftwareGuy sorry my fault, it worked I had copied it wrong. I only need to know, if the variable is not set, how can I test it? I tried with: `var id = getParameterByName('id');
if (id!= '')` and `if (id!= undefined)` both did not work

Comment: @Kaktus I have updated the code to include a working 'if' check.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this excellent javascript url manipulation library:

http://code.google.com/p/jsuri/

You can do stuff like this:

**Getting query param values by name**

Returns the first query param value for the key

```
new Uri('?cat=1&amp;cat=2&amp;cat=3').getQueryParamValue('cat')   // 1
```

Returns all query param values the key

```
new Uri('?cat=1&amp;cat=2&amp;cat=3').getQueryParamValues('cat')  // [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Thank you but I do not want tu include a library, should go without it or? I have seen so many different answers without a library

Comment: @Kaktus The point of using a library is that it has been tested for some time already, while your custom script isn't yet. I think you should consider it seriously, unless you feel quite confortable in debugging / maintaining a side-solution for that.

Comment: Thank you! I understand. I just feel that a whole library is somehow "overblown" for a simple variable in a form. But I consider this! thx

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to get the GET parameters without using a library:

```
var parameters = []
var parts = location.search.substr(1).split('&')

for(var part in parts) {
   var splitted = parts[part].split('=')
   parameters[splitted[0]] = splitted[1]
}
```

Now `parameters` is an array with the parameter name in the key and the value as the value.

**This is a simple solution and may not work for all scenario's.**

Comment: Thank you! This may be useful too